# How to use GetSession from next-auth/react in apollo when rendering serverside?

Tags: next.js, apollo, next-auth

How does one use the getSession to retrive a token when creating the link for apollo client? It works great clientside with getSession.
Serverside it retunes null. I know getSession usally takes a req parameter but that is not present in the apollo client file.

In trying to fetch data in getServerSideProps (nextjs) with a token from the session.

Comment: Could you please provide the relevant code?